# CSRF: can the JSON data returned by a POST request be stolen?

Tags: security, json, csrf

Can the JSON data, returned by a POST request be stolen by a cross-site request forgery attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be done using JS, but I'm not sure about Flash's cross-domain request.

In JS POST request can be made via forms and XMLHTTPRequest. You can't see result of a cross-domain form, so that's safe. XHR forbids cross-domain requests, so that's safe too.

Browsers do allow cross-domain inclusion of scripts via `<script>` element, but that is using GET only.

Comment: But remember that browsers do allow cross-domain form posts.  This attack cannot be used to read JSON data.  But if your POST action has a side-effect a hidden <form/> tag on another site can be used to trigger that side-effect.